# Twitter bootstrap .popover not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get Twitter Bootstrap's .popover working and I've pretty much copied the code on my site, but it tells me Object [object object] has no method 'popover' on inspect element. I've imported jquery before bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js and the files do show up in inspect element. Here's the actual button i'm trying to get a popover for:

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
    $(function(){
            $('#example').popover();
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that tooltip.js needs to be included before popover.js.